# How to Extract a table's data in an external URL

Tags: php, web-scraping, embed, tabular

I'm trying to embed the code of the link below in my own website:

http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/SearchServlet?action=listStationNew&station=%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A6%D0%90&date=28/02/2017

But the problem is that the link is dynamically generated & its trailer changes on a daily basis. How can I extract the tabular data from the link using `PHP` language.

Comment: Please read this and then re-formulate your question to show some effort: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It will help you in asking your questions the right way. Specially make sure to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use date('d/m/Y') for this with curl.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://razpisanie.bdz.bg/SearchServlet?action=listStationNew&station=%D0%94%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%A6%D0%90&date=';

$url = $url.date('d/m/Y');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


echo $output;
```

More info from date: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
More info from curl: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

If your and the razpisanie's server clock don't use same time and date you will get time issue, because you will get a not existing date url when razpisanie's server dont change date.